# function pointers for objects in C

Tags: c, arrays, object, function-pointers

```
typedef struct node{
        int term;
        struct node *next;
}node;
typedef void(*PTR )(void *);
typedef void(*PTR1)(void *,int,int);
typedef int(*PTR2)(void *,int);
typedef void(*PTR3)(void *,int);
typedef void(*PTR4)(void *,void *,void *);

typedef struct list{
      node *front,*rear;
      PTR3 INSERT;
      PTR *MANY;
      PTR DISPLAY,SORT,READ;
      PTR4 MERGE;
}list;

void constructor(list **S)
{
    (*S)=calloc(1,sizeof(list));
    (*S)->front=(*S)->rear=NULL;
    (*S)->INSERT=push_with_value;
    (*S)->READ=read;
    (*S)->SORT=sort;
    (*S)->DISPLAY=display;    
    (*S)->MERGE=merger;    

    (*S)->MANY=calloc(2,sizeof(PTR));
    (*S)->MANY[1]=read; 


}
int main() 
{
    list *S1,*S2,*S3;
    constructor(&S1);
    constructor(&S2);
    constructor(&S3);

    S1->MANY[1](S1);
    S1->SORT(S1);
    S1->DISPLAY(S1);
    return 0;
}
```

The `void *` parameter in all such functions gets typecast to `list *` inside the function.
Is there any way through which I can call `S1->READIT;` by changing the `MANY[1]` to another name like `READ_IT;`?

I intend to create a common header file, so that I can use it for all my programs.
Since I don't know how many function pointers I will need I intend to create a dynamic array of each function pointer type.

Comment: Those ALL CAPS VARIABLE NAMES are very tiring to read.

Comment: Good naming convention is `UpperCamelCase` for types and `lowerCamelCase` for functions and variables. But what's more important is that once you decide to follow some convention, you should keep it that way.

Comment: Thanks for the advice...I'll keep that in mind for coding in the future :)

Comment: Your approach seems to be far more complicated than necessary.

Comment: The more `malloc` and `calloc` calls there will be in your program, the higher is the chance that there will be some memory leak. And array of function pointers and actually all this function pointers stuff is very prone to errors. If someone gives me this code and tells me that this is API that I should use, I wouldn't be very happy about it I can tell.

Answer (score 1):

```
typedef struct list{
  node *front,*rear;
  PTR3 INSERT;
  PTR READIT;
  PTR DISPLAY,SORT,READ;
  PTR4 MERGE;
}list;
```

...

```
(*S)->READIT = read;
```

...

```
S1->READIT(S1);
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the Linux kernel implementation of (doubly linked) lists, as defined [here](http://git.kernel.org/cgit/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/tree/include/linux/list.h) (and following/referenced files). They are used all over the place. Most of the manipulation is done in macros to e.g. run an operation on all nodes of the list.

If what you are trying to define is getting too complicated, step back and look for simpler alternatives. Don't generalize beforehand; if the generalization isn't used it is a waste; if something (slightly) different is later needed, it is a poor match that requires workarounds or even reimplementation.

Take a look at the interfaces exposed by the C++ STL [list](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/list/list/), those folks have thought long and hard on the matter (in a different setting, though).

Or just bite the bullet and use C++ if you want full-fledged OOP.